# What does “ awaiting assessment “ mean within the context of a ScholarOne submission system?

Tags: paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to New Phytologist journal that uses the ScholarOne submission system. The manuscript status has changed to “awaiting assessment “, What does this mean?